# Database of all mailing addresses in France, and their coordinates

Tags: data-request, geospatial, geocoding, address, france

Where can I find all currently valid mailing addresses in France?

As well as the latitude/longitude for each.

Answer (score 4):

The French government has just launched a national open database that aims to contain all currently valid addresses: http://adresse.data.gouv.fr
It is a collaboration between the government, the French National Geographic Institute, the postal service, and OpenStreetMap.

800 megabytes, one CSV file per French departement, WIN1252 encoding.
The data can be downloaded for free under the ODbL license without registration at http://openstreetmap.fr/ban

Excerpt:

```
id,nom_voie,id_fantoir,numero,rep,code_insee,code_post,alias,nom_ld,x,y,commune,fant_voie,fant_ld,lat,lon
ADRNIVX_0000000001948049,Chemin des Acacias,0001,15,"",97401,97425,"","",329906.7,7653235.5,Les Avirons,0001,,-21.214471,55.361181
ADRNIVX_0000000002425821,Chemin des Acacias,0001,11,"",97401,97425,"","",329895.1,7653266.5,Les Avirons,0001,,-21.214190,55.361072
ADRNIVX_0000000002255091,Chemin des Acacias,0001,15,BIS,97401,97425,"","",329875.4,7653241.4,Les Avirons,0001,,-21.214415,55.360880
ADRNIVX_0000000002425822,Chemin des Acacias,0001,60,"",97401,97425,"","",329224.6,7652935,Les Avirons,0001,,-21.217122,55.354581
ADRNIVX_0000000002425943,Chemin des Acacias,0001,19,C,97401,97425,"","",329845.1,7653213.1,Les Avirons,0001,,-21.214668,55.360585
```

[Description of the CSV fields (in French)](http://adresse.data.gouv.fr/static/pdf/Description%20du%20contenu%20du%20produit%20gratuit%20issu%20de%20la%20Base%20Adresse%20Nationale.pdf)
Shapefiles are also available.